# Reportviewer multiple parametres in vb

Tags: vb.net, parameters, reportviewer

If I have in my `ReportViewer` tow parametres named :`[@a1]` and `[@a2]`

Why I cannot do this :

```
For i=0 to 1
ReportViewer1.localreport.setparameteres("a" & i , "hello")
End For
```